# How to add and retrive pdf file on firebase in jetpack compose

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to add pdf file on firebase from admin panel and retrive it in user panel. In jetpack compose. But i am not able to do this.If anyone know about this..plzz answer me

I want code for it.If anyone know about this..please answer me

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase storage to store the pdf file and retrieve it

store :

```
fun uploadPdf() {
    val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("pdfs/myfile.pdf")

    val file = Uri.fromFile(File("path/to/your/file.pdf"))
    storageReference.putFile(file)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
        }
}
```

retrieve:

```
fun getPdfUrl(onResult: (String) -> Unit) {
    val storageReference = 
FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("pdfs/myfile.pdf")

    storageReference.downloadUrl
        .addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
            onResult(uri.toString())
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
        }
}
```

Comment: I did it..But i am not able to show a list of pdf file on user panel screen? How to show the list of pdf file on User Screen.